# incompatible types when assigning to type ‘memstruct’ from type ‘int’

Tags: c, struct, compiler-errors

I get the error "incompatible types when assigning to type ‘memstruct’ from type ‘int’ " in C for the following line:

```
result1 = getValueFromBind(interpret(t->ptr1));.
```

The declarations of result1 and function are as follows:

```
memstruct result1;
memstruct getValueFromBind(memstruct bind);
```

Also, the memstruct function is defined as follows:
    typedef union Constant {
           int intval;
           char* strval;
    }Constant;
    typedef struct memstruct{
        int type;
        Constant value;
    }memstruct;

EDIT : getValueFromBind function returns bind or NULL after a simple check.
       Interpret returns a memstruct. Also, the error is shown at the assignment in C.

Following is Minimalist example(@gsamaras) : http://ideone.com/Rb8ZCd

As dsh answered it, solved the errors in my program

Comment: In function call what is this - `interpret(t->ptr1)` ?  What does it return (assuming it a function ) ?

Comment: why not show a ***complete minimal example*** miney???? :/ :/ :/ -1 until you do.

Comment: Yeah, my guess `interpret()` doesn't return a `memstruct` type.

Comment: A minimal example, is an example that can be compiled and contains the minimum amount of code that generates your problem. :)

Comment: Vishnu thanks for the min ex. Next post this at first sight please. +1 for making the effort. Good that dsh answered your question. You may accept it then! :D

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are missing the [forward declaration](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Forward_declaration) of your function `getValueFromBind()`. In C, for historical reasons, functions that are not declared are assumed to return a type `int`.  Declare the function's [prototype](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Function_prototype) before it is used and then the compiler will know the correct return type.

Comment: @ameyCU You are correct that the OP didn't show enough code to see the absence of the prototype. However, I inferred it based on my experience with this particular error message.

Comment: Will upvote for that dsh. I had to see the example first.

Comment: @gsamaras  Thanks. : )

Answer (score 2):

You use the function, before `main()` knows about it, so you can forward declare it like this:

```
#include  <stdio.h>

typedef struct memstruct{
    int type;
}memstruct;

memstruct interpret(memstruct t); // forward declaration

int main(){
    memstruct t1,t2;
    t1.type = 1;
    t2 = interpret(t1);
    return 1;
}

memstruct getValueFromBind(memstruct bind){
    return bind;
}

memstruct interpret(memstruct t){
    memstruct result1;
    result1 = getValueFromBind(t);
    return result1;
}
```

Or you could just move the whole implementation of `interpret()` before `main()`. However, it should be after the `struct`, since you use it in the function.

You may want to take a look at this: [Function Declaration and Function Prototypes](http://opencbp.sourceforge.net/en_US.ISO8859-1/books/opencbook/func.prototypes.html)

Comment: Thank you, for pointing out the minimalistic example point, will make sure of it from next time.

Comment: You are welcome@Vishnu. I might be a little harsh on you, so take my upvote in your top question so far too, as a sorry! :)